# FILTER_VALIDATE_INT unexpected result

Tags: php, filter-var

I'm using the following code:

```
if(!filter_var($Postings['remainingTokens'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('min-range' => 1))){

$this->redirect(array('upgrade', 'id'=>$id));
}
```

When I have `$Postings['remaingTokens']` equal to 1 or higher it works fine and doesn't execute within the `if` statement. If I have a negative value though it still doesn't execute the `redirect()`. Why is this the case? Apologies if this is simple?

Jonny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is spelled `min_range` not `min-range`.

Comment: Thank you, my mistake. Strangely though my negative value still gives what I think is the wrong number..

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering how I fixed the negative number issue also: I did the following:

```
        $options = array(
    'options' => array(
        'min_range' => 1
        )
    );
filter_var($jobPostings['remainingTokens'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options)
```

Hopefully that is of some use to someone.